# How can I get BufferedReader to read the special symbols

Tags: java, csv, netbeans, utf-8, bufferedreader

I have a file called 'definitions.csv' which contains names of regions in Europe. On each line I have an rgbcode following a regionname. These regionnames however can contain special characters like :
ñ,é,à ...

I have read through some threads here and one of the solutions was to change the BufferedReader(FileReader) to 
BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(FileInputStream(definition.csv"),"UTF-8"))

To no avail unfortunately,when I print out the regionnames in Netbeans I get :
[image: illustration of faulty netbeansoutput]

The method where I extract all data from the CSV-file into one large String.

```
    public String retrieveDefinitionsCSVContent(BufferedReader br) {
    try {
// here the file is read ,using the modified Readers
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(definition.csv"), "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String lijn = br.readLine();
        while (lijn != null) {
            sb.append(lijn);
            sb.append("\n");
            lijn = br.readLine();
        }
        String DefCSV = sb.toString();
        return DefCSV;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        System.out.println("definition.csv not found for readDefinitionCSV()");
    } catch (IOException io) {
        System.out.println("problem occurred reading definition.csv for readDefinitionCSV()");
    }
    return "Error in readDefinitionCSV()";
}
```

The method where I chop up the long String from the previous method,into smaller chunks so I can manipulate and read the data more clearly.

```
    public void initBasicRGB(String definitionCSVContent) {
    System.out.println("initBasicRGB");
    String[] lines = definitionCSVContent.split("\n");
    String[] values;
    int i = 0;
    for (String s : lines) {
        values = s.split(";");
        if (!s.isEmpty() && values.length == 6 && i != 0) {
            int red = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
            int green = Integer.parseInt(values[2]);
            int blue = Integer.parseInt(values[3]);
            String nameProvince = values[4];
// in purgeString I eliminate the special characters by replacing them by their signless counterparts : à=>a (this shouldnt interfere since everything malfunctioned already before I implemented purgeString)
            nameProvince = purgeString(nameProvince);
            basicRGB.put(new Color(red, green, blue), nameProvince);
            System.out.println(new Color(red, green, blue) + "\t" + nameProvince);
            if (isNumber(values[0])) {
                provinceID.put(Integer.parseInt(values[0]), nameProvince);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"These regionnames however can contain special characters like : ñ,é,à ..."* Those aren't "special," they're just characters. More: [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: Are you sure that the CSV is encoded using UTF-8?

Comment: *"To no avail unfortunately,when I print out the regionnames in Netbeans..."* All that tells you is that you're not necessarily outputting to something that understands the encoding you're sending to it. In order to read *and display* the CSV data correctly, you must *read* it using the encoding used to write it (which may or may not be UTF-8), and write it to something that understands the encoding you're writing with. If the CSV is in UTF-8, and you read it in UTF-8, and you output UTF-8 to something that expects to receive UTF-8, you'll be fine. Somewhere there, you're crossing encodings.

Comment: What you showed could have been `"Windows-1252"`. Use a programmer's editor like NotePad++ or JEdit to check .csv encoding. Mind, Windows-1252 is not suited for all latin script encodings in Europe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSV-file was encoded in iso-8859-1 instead of UTF-8.

```
new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\SteamApps\\common\\Crusader Kings II\\common\\landed_titles\\landed_titles.txt"),"iso-8859-1"
```

Comment: It's missing the fairly vital information: *How you know* that it's in ISO-8859-1. Are you guessing? Or is there something specific about the data that suggests it to you? Is there really enough data to say ISO-8849-1 rather than Windows-1252 (which is a superset of it)? Etc.